# Name error: name 'variável' is not defined

Tags: python

Na 2ª parte, na hora de printar 'perd', aparece o erro "Name error: name 'perd' is not defined", como corrijo?

## 1ª parte

```py
def test(usr,val):
  perd = 0
  win = 0
  if usr.upper() == 'A':
    print('SOMA = ',val)
    if val == 21:
      win == 1
    if val > 21:
      perd == 1
  else:
    if val == 21:
      perd == 1
```

## 2ªparte

```py
print("---------",perd)
```

Comment: A parte dois, está fora da função test? Se estiver, a variável realmente não existirá.

Answer (score 0):

Olá viva sem perceber para que serve este código, consigo corrigir o que está mal.... primeiro não consegues aceder à variável **perd** porque está no scope de uma função, ou seja, será utilizada no momento de execução desta e posteriormente será removido de memória com GC, contudo uma forma de aceder aos valores da função deixo abaixo como fazer, retornando o que esta carrega para a variável.

NOTA: Alerto para um erro comum, estava a atribuir valores às variáveis com duplo igual, assim perd == 1, assim nunca irá receber o valor mas sim comparar e poderá retornar um boleano, (se tivesse um return) se a variável perd que foi inicializada a zero é igual a 1, logo retorna um False, a atribuição deverá ser perd = 1. Espero ter esclarecido o que estavas a fazer mal e porquê.

**Solução**

```
def test(usr,val):
  perd = 0
  win = 0
  if usr.upper() == 'A':
    print('SOMA = ',val)
    if val == 21:
      win = 1
    if val > 21:
      perd = 1
    return perd
  else:
    if val == 21:
      perd = 1
    return perd

print(test('A', 221))
```